# Highlight multiple row values based on another value in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a table with 4 columns grouped by first 2 columns. Something like below

```
Company Department  Department Rating   Org     Org Rating  Emp Type    Employee

A       Sales        1                  XX      2           External    John

        Ops          2                  XX      1           Hybrid      Mike

B       HR           1                  YY      2           Internal    Richard

        Dev          3                  ZZ      3           Internal    Julie
```

I want to highlight Department and Org based on values in ratings column (1- yellow, 2- red, 3-blue)

Could anyone guide on how to make it happen on tableau?

Answer (score 0):

Tableau by default will only highlight measure values so in order to highlight dimensions you need to trick it a bit.

1. First, you'll want to create two dummy columns with the formula `min(1)`.  You can either create this through a calculated field or just double click and type them in the columns shelf. 
   [image: min(1)]
2. In the Marks card for each of the two new measures (not the All card), place Department on the text field in one and Org in the text field of the other.  Set the Mark type to be Text on both of them.

[image: Marks card]

3. Create a calculated field to define the colors.  The actual values don't matter here as you'll assign a color to them latter.  Put this on the All marks card on the Color Shelf.

[image: Color Calc]

4. At this point, you might have something like...
   [image: You are here]
5. Now to finish it off you can do a few things:

   - Double click on the color squares in the legend to reassign them
   - Change formatting on the measure to get rid of the axis, zero lines, etc
   - Move the label from the bottom to the top by creating a [dual axis](https://tech.olx.com/tableau-how-to-moving-axis-label-from-bottom-to-top-65ba627cfa53).

Comment: Tableau is so far disappointing. I could do the same thing with report builder with ease. I am trying to get Department with color babsed on department rating and Org based on org rating. Rating may not be the same. And I want Emp Type and EMployee after colored/highlighted value. In above case it is coming before and after both

Comment: Tableau is designed for visual analysis and exploration of data.  Agree that some "basic" things like this could be easier but for its core strengths/purpose it can't be beat.